# PHP textarea input multiplies by two and outputs double input

Tags: php

Quick rundown:

- Everything ran perfectly as it should when I had my own custom textarea field to send data
- I had a custom text editor widget for inputs, but tried to add CKEditor for more functionality
- When I added CKEditor package (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/?undefined-addons=) the editor was there, but when I clicked "Add" button and sent data, the input was doubled and there was a space between inputs (for example - input was:"test" and output was "test`<br><br>`test"), as if I put `<br>` tag and multiplied my input somewhere.
- When I stopped trying with CKEditor, I went back to original code and my own original custom text editor, which before worked perfectly. However, to my surprise, it now still doubles the input string, but it doesn't put a `<br>` tag in between.
- In DB the string value is normal and not doubled.

I have no idea how this happened, I've been going over the code for a hour or so now, trying to see if I overlooked something, but I even created a separate file with functioning code, before I was trying with CKEditor in case something broke and I could just replace it with old code and try tomorrow, but now it's messed up and I have no idea how and where.

[image]

notifications.php

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
</form>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['response'])) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['res_type']; ?> alert-dismissible text-center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <b><?= $_SESSION['response']; ?></b>
        </div>
        <?php } unset($_SESSION['response']); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">
        <?php
          $query = 'SELECT * FROM crud';
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->get_result();
        ?>
        <table class="table table-hover" id="data-table">
          <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><a href='details.php'><img src="<?= $row['photo']; ?>" width="125"></a></td>
              <td class="pt-2"><?= 

                $longString=$row['name']; 
                $link = $row['id'];
                $longStringshortcut = strlen($longString);
                
                //echo substr($longString, 0, 100).'... <a href="$link">Read More</a>';
                    if ($longStringshortcut > 250) {
                        echo substr($longString, 0, 250).".. <a href='details.php?details=$link'><strong>Preberi več...</strong></a>"; }
                    else {
                        echo $longString;
                    }
                
                
                ?>
              
                <a href="details.php?details=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-primary">Details</a> 
                <a href="action.php?delete=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-danger" onclick="return confirm('Do you want delete this record?');">Delete</a> 
                <a href="index.php?edit=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-success">Edit</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-4 p-0">
            <h5 class="">Add notification:</h5>
                <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id; ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="name" value="<?= $name; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="This is the default text" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php if ($update == true) { ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Change notification">
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Add">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="oldimage" value="<?= $photo; ?>">
                        <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file">
                        <img src="<?= $photo; ?>" width="120" class="img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                </form> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

action.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'config.php';

    $update=false;
    $id="";
    $name="";
    $photo="";

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        
        $photo=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $upload="uploads/".$photo;

        $query="INSERT INTO crud(name,photo)VALUES(?,?)";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$upload);
        $stmt->execute();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $upload);

        header('location:index.php');
        $_SESSION['response']="Successfully Inserted to the database!";
        $_SESSION['res_type']="success";
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your editor. Nothing in PHP will do that.

Comment: `<?=` if for echoing content. Use `<?php` to open a PHP block.

Comment: @Barmar not sure what you exactly mean, my previous "text editor" was basically just textarea for input string to be displayed when I click add button. I also added a photo to see what happens now.

Comment: Provide `var_dump($row)` for one of the records providing double content, or every row has double content? Also don't use rendered page to view that, view the source.

Comment: @user3783243, solved. Yeah after my <?=, I also had a small blank space. I replaced that now with <?php and it works normally. I don't know why it worked before then, just the whole situation has been weird. Thanks to others for trying to help!

Comment: You said you went back to your "custom text editor".

Comment: You don't provide the initial contents of a textarea with a `value` attribute. You put it between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`

Comment: @Barmar, I'm not sure we are on the same page. It's fixed now, I'll also paste the edited working code now, maybe you will understand me better or I'm just missing the point you are trying to show me.

Comment: You should post the working code in an Answer, not the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the <?= syntax (echoing), <?php solved it.